# Find PHP Recursive array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am trying to get all the children and sub-children under each category. I have an array but I need to get this in list of category with its correspond child.

These are the given list I want.

```
-Category a
  ---category child b
    -------category child c
  ---category d
-category b
```

This is an array I got return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StudentCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Category A
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [lft] => 1
                    [rght] => 8
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [description] => Category A
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created] => 2014-04-16 19:43:01
                    [updated] => 2014-04-17 02:27:28
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentCategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [name] => Category A
                                    [parent_id] => 1
                                    [lft] => 2
                                    [rght] => 5
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                    [description] => Category A
                                    [is_active] => 1
                                    [is_deleted] => 0
                                    [created] => 2014-04-16 19:44:43
                                    [updated] => 2014-04-17 01:15:39
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [StudentCategory] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 3
                                                    [name] => Category A
                                                    [parent_id] => 2
                                                    [lft] => 3
                                                    [rght] => 4
                                                    [user_id] => 1
                                                    [description] => Category A
                                                    [is_active] => 1
                                                    [is_deleted] => 0
                                                    [created] => 2014-04-16 19:45:39
                                                    [updated] => 2014-04-16 19:45:39
                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentCategory] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => category 2
                                    [parent_id] => 1
                                    [lft] => 6
                                    [rght] => 7
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                    [description] => category 2
                                    [is_active] => 0
                                    [is_deleted] => 0
                                    [created] => 2014-04-16 20:57:28
                                    [updated] => 2014-04-16 20:57:28
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StudentCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => category 21
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [lft] => 9
                    [rght] => 10
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [description] => category 21
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [is_deleted] => 0
                    [created] => 2014-04-16 21:00:33
                    [updated] => 2014-04-16 21:00:33
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I am using this solution for trying to get this done:

```
  $level = 0;
  $catresult = array();
  $ch = $this->Common->make_category_children_array($v['children'],$level,$catresult);
  pr($ch);  

function make_category_children_array($childarray,&$level,&$catresult){

        foreach($childarray as $item){

            $catresult[$level] = $item['StudentCategory'];
            $childarray = $item['children'];
            if (is_array($childarray) && $childarray) { $level++;
                $this->make_category_children_array($childarray,$level,$catresult);
            }
        }

        return $catresult;
    }
```

Comment: The `ltf` and `rght` make this quite likely to be a data structure in an implementation of a "nested set" algorithm. This means that although it can be rendered or explored in a recursive fashion, there are operations that can be done on it that are specifically not recursive.

Comment: I am not getting to sure about the child array. How can I get recursive child array because it can be any no. of length under each category

Comment: I've seen the code update in your question now. Can you outline what problem you are having with it, specifically? Personally I am not sure about the pass-by-reference `&$level` since you are incrementing it inside the `foreach` loop. That will mean a childarray with three items will have `n` for the first item, `n+1` for the second item and `n+2` for the third, which is not correct. I suspect it is better to pass `$level + 1` explicitly and pass by value instead.

Comment: So, the main question is, has your goal now changed? If not, then try my code directly? Did it work?

Comment: How are you getting on with this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps go for something like:

```
 function ex(&$ary, $prefix)
 {
    $retval = '';
    foreach(array_keys($ary) as $i) {
      ...
      $retval .= $prefix + $ary[$i]['StudentCategory']['name'];
      if (array_key_exists($ary[$i], 'children'))
        $retval .= ex($ary[$i]['children'], '---' . $prefix);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the `foreach` to produce keys in `$i` - the `$dummy` is unused.

Comment: `array_keys` might be preferable.

Comment: Ah good idea - go ahead! +1 now it is fixed (not sure the OP is still reading, but it may be useful for someone else).

Comment: Done.  (crikey, my PHP is rusty!)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution might look a little bit like the following:

```
/**
 * An initial function to set up the recursive loop
 */
function explore(array $structure)
{
    exploreLevel($structure, 0);
}

/**
 * The actual recursion happens in here
 */
function exploreLevel(array $subStructure, $level)
{
    foreach ($subStructure as $item)
    {
        // Let's render the category here. The repeated spaces give us
        // some indentation depending where we are in the hierarchy
        $category = $item['StudentCategory'];
        echo str_repeat('  ', $level) . $category . "\n";

        // Only recurse if the key is an array and it is not empty
        $children = $item['children'];
        if (is_array($children) && $children)
        {
            exploreLevel($children, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Although the nested set algorithm can be explored and modified using non-recursive algorithms, this data structure is specifically hierarchical, and was probably built recursively. Hence, we need a recursive function to explore it.

A popular approach in recursive programming is to pass a level number, initially zero, and incrementing by one as it calls itself. Thus, as the series of calls gets deeper, it explores level 0, level 0 + 1, level 0 + 1 + 1, and so on. This series continues for as long as there are more levels to explore. The `$level` counter is also useful if we wish to add a limit to the depth of exploration.

Comment: I am totally agree with you. First I need to show the category name then an arrow to explore more and more deeper ..You code really gives me good idea to solve it... I am trying to do this with first show an category name and then show its sub-category more and more

Comment: If you are rendering this in a web context, you might want to modify this so it converts the data structure you have to a simple array containing entries that contain "category" and "level". This will allow you to render the categories without stuffing too much business logic in your presentation layer.

Comment: $ch = $this->Common->make_category_children_array($v['children'],$level,$catresult);

_______

 


function make_category_children_array($childarray,&$level,&$catresult){
  
  foreach($childarray as $item){
   
   $catresult[$level] = $item['StudentCategory'];
   $childarray = $item['children'];
   if (is_array($childarray) && $childarray) { $level++;
    $this->make_category_children_array($childarray,$level,$catresult);
   }
  }
   
  return $catresult;
 }

Comment: I am trying to use the refrense for variable to store its previous level value

Comment: ^ @alex: that code is probably best as an addendum to your question - it's not very readable here, or clear what you are doing